# Pasting together subsetted columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, tidyr

I want to paste together some columns with some text where they are combined only if at least one is not NA and the current solution I have works, but is cumbersome. So I am wondering if there is a neater way to do this (to create the "combine" column below). I would like to have used tidyr but there doesn't seem to be a way to specify how to treat missing values in unite()

Thanks and I hope I haven't missed something obvious.

```
df = data.frame(num=c(1,2,NA,NA),place=c("Rome",NA,"Paris",NA))

df$combine[!is.na(df$num)|!is.na(df$place)] = 
  paste(df$num[!is.na(df$num)|!is.na(df$place)],
        "days in",df$place[!is.na(df$num)|!is.na(df$place)]) 

# df
#   num place          combine
# 1   1  Rome   1 days in Rome
# 2   2  <NA>     2 days in NA
# 3  NA Paris NA days in Paris
# 4  NA  <NA>             <NA>
```

Comment: Combining columns sounds like a job for `cbind()`.

Comment: why do you need rows where all values are NA? Can't you just remove the rows with all NAs and simply `paste` the rest?

Comment: "2 days in NA" or "NA days in Paris" as output makes sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself computing the same thing (here: index) again, try to store it and reuse that object to avoid redundant computation. For your example, you could compute the non-NA index as follows:

```
idx <- rowSums(!is.na(df)) > 0
```

Then, you can use that to paste the relevant rows together:

```
df[idx, "combine"] <- with(df[idx, ], paste(num, "days in", place))
```

Comment: If you have more than those two columns in your original data, change the first line to `idx <- rowSums(!is.na(df[, c("num", "place")])) > 0`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate` with `ifelse` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(combine = ifelse(rowSums(!is.na(.))>0, paste(num, "days in", place), NA))
#    num place          combine
#1   1  Rome   1 days in Rome
#2   2  <NA>     2 days in NA
#3  NA Paris NA days in Paris
#4  NA  <NA>      <NA>
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, !Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, is.na))], combine := paste(num, "days in", place)]
df
#   num place          combine
#1:   1  Rome   1 days in Rome
#2:   2    NA     2 days in NA
#3:  NA Paris NA days in Paris
#4:  NA    NA               NA
```